# User Auth With AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase-authentication

I just started angularfire Auth! And i get this problem when i sign in, And if you guys have any advice on how to make a email registration form i would be more than glad to hear that . Here is the error i receive :

> Error: Firebase.authWithPassword failed: First argument must be a valid object.

Here is my 
**script.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('LoginApp', ["firebase"])
app.controller('AuthCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth) {

  var ref = new Firebase('https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/')
  $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  $scope.signIn = function(){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/')
    ref.authWithPassword('email', {
        email: $scope.signInEmail,
        password: $scope.signInPassword
    }, function(error,userData){
        if(error = 'INVALID_EMAIL'){
            alert("The Email you entered is Invalid")
        }
        else if(error = 'INVALID_PASSWORD'){
            alert("The Password you entered is Invalid")
        }
        else{
            console.log(error)
        }
    })

  }
  }]
  );
```

and our **Index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Login - UniqueCoders</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="LoginApp">
    <div id="page">
        <header class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-UXr_le-DEc4/VogTLE2yDfI/AAAAAAAAAfI/9RycRDVGNu8/w993-h207-no/uniquecoders.png" alt="UniqueCoders">
            </div>
        </header>
        <main class="container">
            <div class="row login">
                <form ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model = "signInemail" id="email">
                    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model = "signInpassword" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click = "signIn()">
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <small>&copy; 2016. Unique Coders</small>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- Scripts at the end for faster loading -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the first argument: `ref.authWithPassword('email',`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation here is what i see: 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword({
    "email": "yourname@email.com",
    "password": "password"
  }, function(error, authData) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    }
});
```

Can you change it above and check if it works. Here is a neat example on how to do authentication with angularjs.

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx

Comment: Thalivar but thats checking for a specific email. I want like to check if it has all emails. And thankyou so much for that link! :D

Comment: @JohnDoe: Where in your code you are checking for all emails.